# Issues with qbeta and pbeta

Tags: sampling, beta-distribution, numerical-integration

I'm trying to get samples from truncated beta. I have written the following function 
based on inverse transform sampling method to do so, however, it seems that when CDF converges to 1 fast, pbeta and qbeta have some numerical issues.

```
rTruncBeta <- function(n, alpha, beta, lbound, ubound) {
 F0 <- pbeta(lbound, alpha, beta)
 F1 <- pbeta(ubound, alpha, beta)
 U <- runif(n, F0, F1)
 qbeta(U, alpha, beta)
}
```

Suppose we need to generate samples from truncated beta between .39 and .43 with $\alpha = .1$ and $\beta = 57$.But sometimes this function generates 1 rather than generating between the two bounds. How to fix this issue (of course without sampling more and discarding the 1s)

```
> rTruncBeta(10,.1, 57,.39, .43)

[1] 0.3937340 0.3920652 0.3928667 1.0000000 0.4004606 0.3924584   
   1.0000000 0.3902923 0.3913201 0.4046171
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `pbeta(0.39,0.1,57)` is about $1-3.6\times 10^{-15}$ and  `pbeta(0.43,0.1,57)` is about $1-7.0\times 10^{-17}$.

Near-total loss of numerical accuracy is the problem.

Indeed, getting "1"s is far from your only issue here. If I generate a sample from your function and a better alternative in that region of the parameter space (see below)  and put into tb and tb2 respectively:

```
tbi <- tb[tb<.5]
qqplot(tb2[1:length(tbi)],tbi)
```

so as to compare the quantiles:

[image: qq plot of OP's quantiles against mine]

you can see that your function is far from continuous, taking only a few distinct values at the upper half of its interval.

You could put tests in your TruncBeta function to avoid such catastrophic loss of accuracy - if you check when you're in the far tail like that, you can always call something similar that retains a lot more significant figures (and so will look more like what you expect it to). For example, up in the extreme tail, try something like

```
rTruncBeta2 <- function(n, alpha, beta, lbound, ubound) {
 S0 <- pbeta(lbound, alpha, beta, lower.tail=FALSE)
 S1 <- pbeta(ubound, alpha, beta, lower.tail=FALSE)
 U <- runif(n, S1, S0)
 1-qbeta(U, beta, alpha)
}
```

Comment: perhaps the accuracy could be further improved by working on the log scale. I.e., using the `log.p` argument of both `pbeta()` and `qbeta()`, e.g., compare `qbeta(pbeta(0.39, 0.1, 57), 0.1, 57)` with `qbeta(pbeta(0.39, 0.1, 57, log.p = TRUE), 0.1, 57, log.p = TRUE)`. In addition, in your `rTruncBeta2()` accuracy could be further improved by replacing `1-qbeta(U, beta, alpha)` with `qbeta(U, beta, alpha, lower.tail = FALSE)`.

Comment: I didn't include that last suggestion deliberately. The log suggestion would be a good idea.